# Setters not seeming to work in main method

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I am having trouble using setter methods from the main class with a JFrame "position". The active parts of the JFrame(triangles called "turtles" moving about) are leaving the JFrame and my current method of changing the coordinates when this happens is not working. Any help would be greatly appreciated, as I have been stuck for days.

The method wrapPosition is designed to change the coordinate if they're off the "screen" which is (800x600)pixels. This check is in the loop so a turtle never goes off the screen.

here is the Main Class:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;

class Lab7b
{

    public static void main(String [ ] args) 
    {
        int deltaTime = 50;
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas();                       
        frame.setTitle("Welcome to turtle land!");
        frame.setSize(800, 600);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);       
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.add(canvas);              

        ArrayList<DynamicTurtle> turtles = new ArrayList<DynamicTurtle>(); //An ArrayList containing Turtle elemenets

               turtles.add(new RandomTurtleA(turtleCanvas, 400, 300));  
        turtles.add(new RandomTurtleA(turtleCanvas, 400, 300));
        turtles.add(new RandomTurtleA(turtleCanvas, 400, 300));             

        while(true)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < turtles.size(); i++)
            {
                (turtles.get(i)).unDrawTurtle();
                hello.setText("X: " + (turtles.get(i)).getPositionX() + "    Y: " + (turtles.get(i)).getPositionY()); //print to JFRAME
                System.out.println("X: " + (turtles.get(i)).getPositionX() + "    Y: " + (turtles.get(i)).getPositionY()); //print to CMD

                (turtles.get(i)).wrapPosition((turtles.get(i)).getPositionX(), (turtles.get(i)).getPositionY()); //this is the wrapPosition method that does not work
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < turtles.size(); i++)
            {
                (turtles.get(i)).update(1000);  
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < turtles.size(); i++)
            {
                (turtles.get(i)).drawTurtle();              
            }

        Utils.pause(deltaTime/2);
        }   
    }
}
```

the Turtle class with the troublesome wrapPosition method:

```
class Turtle 
{
    protected Canvas canvas; // private field reference to a canvas private           
    private CartesianCoordinate myLocation, oldLocation; 
    private boolean penDown = true;
    private double Angle, maxX, maxY, x, y;
    public double d, e, first, second;


    public Turtle(Canvas canvas, CartesianCoordinate initLocation) 
    {
        this.canvas = canvas;
        this.myLocation = new CartesianCoordinate(0,0);
        Angle = 0;
        penDown = true;
        myLocation = initLocation.copy();        
    }

    public void wrapPosition(double x, double y)
    {
        this.x = maxX;
        this.y = maxY; 

        if(maxX < 0)
        {
            this.setPositionX(800);
        }

        if(maxX > 800)
        {
            this.setPositionX(0);
        }

        if(maxY < 0)
        {
            this.setPositionY(600);
        }

        if(maxY > 600)
        {
            this.setPositionY(0);
        }        
    }


    public double getPositionX()
    {
        double getPosX;
        getPosX = myLocation.getX();
        return getPosX;
    }

    public double getPositionY()
    {
        double getPosY;
        getPosY = myLocation.getY();
        return getPosY;
    }

    public void setPositionX(double x)
    {
        myLocation.setX(x);
    }

    public void setPositionY( double y)
    {        
        myLocation.setY(y);
    }    
}
```

Also, if it is any help the coordinate class:

```
class CartesianCoordinate
{
    private double xPosition, yPosition, setterX, setterY;  

    public CartesianCoordinate(double x, double y)
    {
        this.xPosition = x;
        this.yPosition = y;
    }

    public double getX()
    {
        return this.xPosition;
    }

    public double getY()
    {
        return this.yPosition;
    }

    public void setX(double setterX)
    {
        this.setterX = xPosition;
    }

    public void setY(double setterY)
    {
        this.setterY = yPosition;
    }
}
```

Any Help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The "setters" in class `CartesianCoordinate` do virtually nothing because they just assign to member variables which are not read.

```
public void setX(double setterX)
{
    this.setterX = xPosition;
}

public void setY(double setterY)
{
    this.setterY = yPosition;
}
```

Try these instead to have coordinates to be read be updated:

```
public void setX(double setterX)
{
    this.xPosition= setterX;
}

public void setY(double setterY)
{
    this.yPosition= setterY;
}
```